# Are these two definitions equivalent?

Tags: general-topology

> If $\langle A_n : n \in \omega  \rangle$ is a sequence of subsets of a set $X$, 
>   $$ \underline{Lim} A_n = \{ x \in X : \exists n_0 \in \omega \forall n \geq n_0, x \in A_n \} $$
>   If $\mathcal A$ is a family of subsets of a set $X$, then, $L(\mathcal A)$ denotes the smallest family of subsets of $X$ containing $\mathcal A$ and closed under $\underline{Lim}$.

Also:

> An open cover $\mathcal U$ of $X$ is called a **$\gamma$-cover** if for every $x \in X$, the set $\{ U \in  \mathcal U ; x \notin U \}$, is finite.

Let, $\mathcal U$ be an open cover of $X$, such that $X \in L(\mathcal U)$. Does this imply that $\mathcal U$ is a $\gamma$-cover of $X$?

These two definitions seem equivalent to me.I have seen both of these definitions in different articles in selection principles. Am I right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of a topological space $X$ containing $X$ will satisfy $X \in L(\mathcal{U})$, but there are clearly open covers with are not $\gamma$-covers which contain $X$.

In slightly more generality, if $\mathcal{U}$ is an open cover of $X$ such that $X \in L(\mathcal{U})$, then for any open cover $\mathcal{V} \supseteq \mathcal{U}$ we will have $X \in L(\mathcal{V})$, but in general $\mathcal{V}$ will not be a $\gamma$-cover. (For example $\mathcal{U} = \{ ( - \infty , n ) : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is a $\gamma$-cover of $\mathbb{R}$, however $\mathcal{V} = \mathcal{U} \cup \{ ( a , b ) : a < b \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ is not.)

Every *infinite* open $\gamma$-cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ will satisfy $X \in L(\mathcal{U})$, since taking any sequence $\langle U_n \rangle_{n \in \omega}$ of distinct elements of $\mathcal{U}$ we will have that $\underline{\mathrm{Lim}}_n U_n = X$.  (I think $\gamma$-covers are usually defined to be infinite anyway.)

Comment: I see. ok. Thank you!!