# Does any $\omega$-cover in which $X \in L(\mathcal U)$ is also a $\gamma$-cover?

Tags: general-topology, combinatorial-game-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

As a continuation to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775573/are-these-two-definitions-equivalent) question:

> An $\omega$-cover, is an open cover $\mathcal U$ of $X$, such that, $X \notin \mathcal U$, and for every finite set $F \subset X$, there exists an open set $U \in \mathcal U$, such that, $F \subset U$.

Let $\mathcal U$, be an $\omega$-cover of $X$, such that, $X \in L(\mathcal U)$. Does this imply that $\mathcal U$, is also a $\gamma$-cover?

(This question of mine is a consequence of trying to prove that 
$\delta \Rightarrow \epsilon$ in page 153 [here](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0166864182900657/1-s2.0-0166864182900657-main.pdf?_tid=b5206272-d108-11e3-8a8f-00000aacb35f&acdnat=1398932288_51d8a3fcc72d04c43369a1e707f41180))

Thank you!

Comment: are you proving that $\delta$ implies $\varepsilon$ still?

Comment: Because we don't need $\gamma$-covers for that result, as the proof sketch in the paper is perfectly straightforward.

Comment: It's not customary to demand $X \notin \mathcal{U}$ in the definition of an $\omega$-cover. If $X$ happens to be an element of the cover then it is an $\omega$-cover trivially. This is in fact used in the proof of $\delta$ implies $\varepsilon$!